# Are there any support tools like coderush or resharper for F#?

Tags: f#

Are there any support tools like coderush or resharper for F#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[F# Refactor](http://fsharprefactor.codeplex.com/) open source project on CodePlex (Apache license).

Answer (score 11):

Preview version of FSharpRefactor released in Visual Studio Gallery.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/339cbae9-911d-4f99-9033-3c3564676f45

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6-YjUULNCA/

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the open-source [Visual F# Power Tools](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/) project. They've got a rename refactoring, some code generation stuff (eg. record stub generation), graying out of unused declarations, as well as some other things. They're moving pretty fast at the moment, with lots of new features getting added all the time.

Answer (score 8):

There's an effort to support F# in ReSharper via an external plug-in (itself written in F#). You can find preliminary info [here](http://activemesa.com/fsharper).

Comment: This project is no longer on GitHub. Moved or dead?

Comment: @bentayloruk the project is currently being restructured. the reason is that it started using some features that were resharper-internal (e.g., r#'s own parser gen). things have changed, and that tech will be part of r#7 sdk. thus, the fsharper project will be posted back once it's updated to use those.

Comment: Now it looks like the project is dead and nothing in Resharper helps with F#. It is sad.

Answer (score 3):

FSharpRefactor 0.1 (Preview version) Released on the Visual Studio Gallery.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/339cbae9-911d-4f99-9033-3c3564676f45?SRC=Home

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, as far as I know. I was also looking for something similar to no success. I suspect as soon as F# hits VS2010 as its integral part, or even a bit earlier, such tools will eventually emerge.

As far as ReSharper is concerned, you may want to drop JetBrains a quick email, it would be interesting to know whether these guys have any plans regarding F#.

Answer (score 1):

Since the push in f# is towards light mode the reformatting possible is likely to be both limited, and hard to implement.

Normally reformatting takes the structural information and uses that to create the textual position. In the case of #light the textual position (of indenting at least) *is* the structure. As such any reformatting would be at best to sort inter symbol spacing, hardly onerous to do yourself.

I would therefore not expect a commercial product for it at least until the 'proper' integration with the IDE (I do not consider the current CTP proper in this regard since several outstanding bugs with it exist which will not be fixed in 2008)

Comment: But the F# compiler is apache licensed, so you don't need to start from scratch.  In fact, the intellisense is just the compiler with the back end chopped off.

Comment: @Rick I agree, but I'm saying that writing a comercial tool is not likely to be worth the cost/benefit trade off given that the f# compiler is not so 'friendly' in trying to get structure from incomplete (read broken) code as say c# (whose compiler does an *awful* lot of work in that regard, take a look at the Roslyn CTP. That the f# compiler is open source under a very permissive licence does make this much more palatable I freely concede. I'd also love to be proved wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

CodeRush is working in F# editor. At least some code assistance and code templates. But code templates are not defined yet (you have to create your own).