# Can CodeRush plugins target languages other than C# or VB?

Tags: plugins, coderush

I am trying to write a CodeRush plugin that works similar to the XML Doc Comment Painter. 
My plugin, which uses a TileVisual adornment, works fine for decorating comments in C# files, but does not work for comments in F# files.

How can I specify that my plugin should be enabled for F# files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491415/are-there-any-support-tools-like-coderush-or-resharper-for-f)? One of the guys there suggests that

> CodeRush is working in F# editor. At least some code assistance and
>   code templates. But code templates are not defined yet (you have to
>   create your own).

If you need help with your own plugin, I think you should better contact Devexpress support.

Answer (score 0):

F# language is not supported at the moment, unfortunately. So, you can not enable the plug-in for this language.