# Find dead code in f# program

Tags: f#, dead-code

Is there a tool that detects unused code in F# programs?

Tools for F# have been discussed from time to time, but it has been a while since this question:

[Are there any support tools like coderush or resharper for F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491415/are-there-any-support-tools-like-coderush-or-resharper-for-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that performs dead code analysis for F# right now.

That said, the recently-released [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service) project certainly makes implementing such tools easier now.

A while back, one or two of the JetBrains developers experimented with a ReSharper language service for F#, but I don't think they ever got to the point where it was usable in production. Maybe now that `FSharp.Compiler.Service` is available, perhaps work can start up again. If you want to see their work: https://github.com/JetBrains/FSharper

Comment: FYI: here is [a discussion](https://github.com/JetBrains/FSharper/issues/51#issuecomment-31168888) about FSharper and FSharp.Compiler.Service. Key takeaway: We should wait for another initiative rather than FSharper.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following project settings:

```
Visual Studio > Solution >
    Project > Build > General > Other flags > --warnon:1182
```

This will warn on unused functions and values when code gets compiled.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the path? At least it sounds very promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181613/hidden-features-of-f